# Match a person in a picture

Tags: image-recognition

I have a *mugshot* (a photo of a person's face) and a *picture* (an arbitrary image file, can be literally anything: another mugshot, a group photo, a cartoon, a poster, a document scan).

I want to determine whether the person whose *mugshot* I have appears in the *picture* (with the confidence score).

**Is there an OTS software to do that?**

Obviously, since "face recognition" is a "solved problem", there is software that does it, the question is more like "where do I get it" and "how well does it work".

Thanks.

Comment: Face recognition is **not** a solved problem, although you can find software that will attempt it, it is still a very active area of research. Assuming you are capable of putting together the necessary ML pipeline, you could try OpenFace: https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/

Comment: @NeilSlater - THANKS! this is precisely what I was looking for! (and yes, I know that this is "a very active area of research" - this is why I put "solved problem" in quotes. Could you please turn your comment into an answer so that I could accept it and close the question?

Comment: Actually I have voted to close the question, as IMO it's not really about Data Science. But I thought I'd link the library in the comments, since I'd like to help

Comment: I think face recognition is very much about DS, and we already have the software-recommendation tag. Where do you think this question _would_ be on topic?!

Comment: First, yes, you can vote to close _and_ answer. Second, you can retract your close vote. Third, the existence of the `software-recommendation` tag makes my question on-topic by default.

Comment: "Third, the existence of the software-recommendation tag makes my question on-topic by default" I disagree. The question still needs to focus on a data science issue, not just use a product of data science research. Perhaps explain what data science you hope to do with the software? Otherwise the question is similar to e.g. "Please recommend me a style transfer image plugin?" or "Please advise on best choice for text autocomplete library in my messaging app?"

Comment: I am asking for DS software recommendation. This is a DS site.

Comment: I'm not sure that requests for recommendations of a software tool/package are on-topic here (even if the software uses machine learning or data science internally).  See https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2191/8560 and https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ and the discussion about "shopping questions".